# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with corePoolSize = 0 causes 100% load on one CPU core

Tags: java, performance

Given is the following configuration of a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) that runs a simple task every five seconds:

```
int corePoolSize = 0;
ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);

Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("XXX");
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

On Oracle JRE `1.8.0_66` there’s one thread created by the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` that constantly causes 100% load on one CPU core.
Investigating the thread dump reveals the following stacktrace:

```
"pool-1-thread-1" - Thread t@10
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.poll(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

With `corePoolSize = 1` there is still one thread in the pool. However, the thread is basically always in state `TIMED_WAITING` and thus idle.

Is the behavior of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with `corePoolSize = 0` a known feature, an unvalidated misconfiguration or even a bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you have hit [JDK-8129861](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129861) that has been fixed in Java 9. It may also be related to [JDK-8022642](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022642).