# Linux top command reporting high CPU usage for Java ThreadPoolExecutor thread in Waiting state (after updating Jetty server from 9.0.6 to 9.4.22)

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, embedded-jetty, corretto

I have a web service which receives requests and after performing certain validations dumps data to a Message Queue. This service creates a ThreadPoolExecutor internally. I use Prometheus and Grafana to visualize application metrics and observed that CPU usage is always increasing and never reducing even during low workload (even if I detach the application from Load Balancer and serve no traffic).

Earlier I was running application using Jetty 9.0.6 and am observing this behavior after switching to Jetty 9.4.22. Reverting back to Jetty 9.0.6 (or even 9.4.13) seems to resolve this issue. So I suspect this might be related to Jetty (9.4.13+).

So I tried to analyze top command output and connect to application using VisualVM at the same time.

Linux top command reported that a certain thread from the ThreadPoolExecutor was using high CPU with CPU time over 500 minutes, however Visual VM showed that the thread is in waiting state.

`top` command output (Few threads report high CPU usage for prolonged duration like following when they're actually in WAITING state)

```
10641 app        20   0 30.4g  21g 112m S 47.9 70.2 657:12.56 657:12 pool-5-thread-1
10914 app        20   0 30.4g  21g 112m R 33.7 70.2 508:25.46 508:25 pool-5-thread-1
10009 app        20   0 30.4g  21g 112m R 33.7 70.2 454:39.50 454:39 pool-5-thread-5
10220 app        20   0 30.4g  21g 112m S 33.7 70.2 444:55.14 444:55 pool-5-thread-7
12230 app        20   0 30.4g  21g 112m R 32.8 70.2 438:18.02 438:18 pool-5-thread-2
```

The thread state from Thread Dump

```
pool-5-thread-1
priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f13b0033000 - nativeId:0x8c9 - nativeId (decimal):2249 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x000000037ca83da0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

pool-5-thread-5
priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f13a0020800 - nativeId:0x8cd - nativeId (decimal):2253 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x000000037ca83da0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

pool-5-thread-7
priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f139c021800 - nativeId:0x8cf - nativeId (decimal):2255 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x000000037ca83da0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

pool-5-thread-2
priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f13bc021800 - nativeId:0x8ca - nativeId (decimal):2250 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x000000037ca83da0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I need help understanding if this could be related to switching from `Oracle JDK 8u65` to `Amazon Corretto JDK 8u232`

CPU usage as monitored in EC2 console
[image: CPU usage as monitored in EC2 console]

Update:
Full top output (from another occurrence) -

```
top - 12:16:34 up  5:03,  0 users,  load average: 10.64, 9.74, 9.72
Threads: 7123 total,  10 running, 7113 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 28.3 us, 16.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 54.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.9 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32121548 total, 26088752 used,  6032796 free,   134028 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  2008744 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5660 app        20   0 30.582g 0.021t  97556 S 47.0 69.6 128:42.34 pool-5-thread-3
 4804 app        20   0 30.582g 0.021t  97556 R 49.6 69.6  98:41.07 pool-5-thread-1
 2695 app        20   0 30.582g 0.021t  97556 R 49.9 69.6  93:10.97 pool-5-thread-5
 2392 app        20   0 30.582g 0.021t  97556 S 48.0 69.6  79:47.46 pool-5-thread-9
 2284 app        20   0 30.582g 0.021t  97556 S  3.2 69.6  13:04.52 pool-5-thread-2
```

JVM flags being used -

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70
-Xss228k
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20
-XX:GCLogFileSize=512M
-Xloggc:/home/app/logs/gc/${CURRENT_DATETIME}.log
-Xms100m
-Xmx${JAVA_XMX}m
-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=${CPUS}
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=200m
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6001
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6001
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${HOST}
-XX:+UsePerfData
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have hit JDK-8129861 that has been fixed in Java 9. It may also be related to JDK-8022642.

The workaround is to set core pool size at least 1:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

References:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129861
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022642

[ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with corePoolSize = 0 causes 100% load on one CPU core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615125/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-with-corepoolsize-0-causes-100-load-on-one-cpu-co)

Comment: We are not creating a thread pool with 0 core threads.